# Apache Cordova - iOS: ld: framework not found GooglePlus

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using Apache Cordova to develop an app, and am trying to make it work on iOS, but a plugin I am using for Google Login is giving me trouble.

The plugin in question is: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

And when I try to build, I get: ld: framework not found GooglePlus

```
Ld /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pass_Manager-gaxgomamsmvhnodgaqpeoiuajsrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pass\ Manager.app/Pass\ Manager normal x86_64
cd "/Users/nicholas/Documents/PhoneGap/Pass Manager/platforms/ios"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pass_Manager-gaxgomamsmvhnodgaqpeoiuajsrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pass_Manager-gaxgomamsmvhnodgaqpeoiuajsrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -FPass\ Manager/Plugins/cordova-plugin-googleplus -filelist /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pass_Manager-gaxgomamsmvhnodgaqpeoiuajsrc/Build/Intermediates/Pass\ Manager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pass\ Manager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pass\ Manager.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework AssetsLibrary -framework GooglePlus /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pass_Manager-gaxgomamsmvhnodgaqpeoiuajsrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework CoreGraphics -framework GoogleSignIn -framework MobileCoreServices -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework GoogleSignIn -weak_framework AddressBook -weak_framework CoreText -framework GooglePlus -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -weak-lz -weak-lz -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pass_Manager-gaxgomamsmvhnodgaqpeoiuajsrc/Build/Intermediates/Pass\ Manager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pass\ Manager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pass\ Manager_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pass_Manager-gaxgomamsmvhnodgaqpeoiuajsrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pass\ Manager.app/Pass\ Manager

ld: framework not found GooglePlus
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Even after I have added the GooglePlus.framework to my project, I still get a failed build:

My current project looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQcYP.png

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed Plugin Using CLI? Then can you please remove plugin and try again.